# Finding good Escape Rooms in Budapest?

Tags: nightlife, activities, hungary, budapest, local-knowledge

Escape Rooms/Games are a relatively new entertainment that seem to be cropping up in cities across the world. I've been reading over and over again that Budapest has a lot of escape rooms -- is this something that Budapest is known for? Are they more known for Escape Rooms than the rest of Europe? **Did it start there?** Assuming that it did, does that mean the escape rooms are high quality there? Here's a [CNN article](http://www.cnn.com/2014/05/21/travel/gallery/budapest-escape-game/index.html) I came across.

My sister and I are both young adults who do not drink alcohol or enjoy clubbing, but would still very much like to do something in the evenings while we are in Budapest for one night. I would like for it to be significant to Budapest. Escape rooms would seem to fit the bill; I'd like some advice on how to choose a good one.

Comment: As I understand it, a specific question on Escape Rooms would be acceptable, but the part asking "What other activities are available?" is too generic.

Comment: Don't assume that because Escape Rooms started in Budapest, the quality of them is higher. There are some very bad ones too, pick carefully.

Comment: @AndyT, thanks for your feedback. I edited it so it focuses solely on the Escape Room aspect. Does that make it suitable?

Comment: @ytg, yeah... that's what I'm afraid of! I noticed that there are a lot of options... but with all those options that means potentially a lot of sucky escape rooms. Do you have any tips on how to choose a quality one?

Comment: @ButterflyandBones I decided that your comment is actually the answerable question here, so I've edited. Does it look ok to you?

Comment: @KateGregory, yes, it looks much, much better! Thank you so much for taking the time to do that! You hit the nail on the head! :)

Comment: I've only seen bad and mediocre ones at Budapest, but here are a bunch of them, which are known to support English: http://exitgames.hu/jatekhelyszinek?game_filter[city]=Budapest&game_filter[category]=&game_filter[prop0]=on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Budapest has quite a few these certainly it didn't start there.

It started in the Silicon Valley in 2006 but "Real Escape Games" became immensely popular in Japan and spread to Hong Kong, Singapore, China and Taiwan. The first one in Budapest opened in 2011 and began to really spread in 2012.

For two people, it's very likely http://paraparkbudapest.hu/en is the best, they are the oldest and one of the few that are enjoyable by two people, most are optimized for teams of 3-5 people. Have fun, Budapest is great to visit! (Just don't get sick.)